# Crear una consulta utilizando una sola tabla, en SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Listar los nombres de los empleados y el nombre de su respectivo jefe (solo los que tiene jefe).[usar joins]

[image: Esquema de la base de datos]

**SELECT * TABLE empleado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: Lo que he intentado]
[image: Ejecutado]

Lo que deseo es, si supervisor es 3 entonces que aparezca el nombre de Karolina, que es el que corresponde.

**> Mejor respuesta ejecutada.**

[image: Respuesta]

**Pero aun tengo un problema, los supervisores Karolina (3) y Glenda (2) Se cruzan. Lo que se espera es lo siguiente.**

[image: Esperado]

Comment: Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: En las columnas de supervisor tendria que quedar.

1 - Elena
3 - Karolina
2 - Glenda
3 - Karolina

No se como expresarlo mejor

Comment: O no me aclaro, o has planteado mal los ejemplos de la pregunta.
¿Y además quieres que en una sola celda se muestren dos datos? Ej: 1-Elena (id, nombre)?

Comment: @rencinas arriba actualice que es lo que espero obtener y el resultado de establecer la relacion de empleado.codigo a empleado.supervisor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Necesitas hacer join con la misma tabla pero cuando el código de  `empleado_1` es igual al supervisor de `empleado`:

```
SELECT empleado.codigo,
empleado.nombre,
empleado.supervisor,
empleado_1.nombre
FROM empleado
INNER JOIN empleado AS empleado_1
ON empleado_1.codigo = empleado.supervisor
```

**Updated: 07-11-2016**

Comment: Exactamente es lo que deseaba. Soy nuevo en esto. Muchas gracias.

Comment: no me habia dado cuenta pero, si te fijas bien Karolina y Glenda estan crusados, Glenda deberia ser el 2 y Karolina el 3

Comment: Se estaba mostrando el id del supervisor del supervisor. Ahora debería estar bien.

Comment: aun tengo el problema, la ultima imagen es como espero que quede, la penúltima imagen es tu código ejecutado.

Comment: Creo que la tabla que esperas no es correcta, en ella se ve que Glenda es la supervisora de Glenda. Según lo que se deduce de la primera query Karolina es la supervisora de Glenda. También se ve que Glenda es supervisora de Karolina, lo cual no tiene mucho sentido pero es lo que se ve en tu primer query.

Comment: He agregado la imagen de un SELECT a la tabla empleado. Puedes revisarla.

Comment: Eso confirma las sospechas. La tabla que esperas es incorrecta, ya que dice que Glenda es supervisora de Glenda, pero en la tabla inicial se ve Glenda es supervisora de Karolina, y Karolina de Glenda, que es justo lo que devuelve la query de la respuesta.

Comment: muchas gracias. No me fije bien.